# Elevation Map from Slope and Aspect Rasters

Tags: raster, dem, elevation

I am trying to create an elevation map (e.g., recreate a DEM) from the following input data:

- Slope Raster
- Aspect Raster
- ASCII file containing XYZ data points (Easting, Northing, and Elevation for about a dozen locations)

I cannot find any information on how to go about doing so. Also worth noting that I did not create the slope and aspect rasters from an original DEM.

Comment: What kind of data is in the ascii file?

Comment: Easting, Northing, and Elevation for about a dozen locations.

Comment: The interpolation used to create the slope and aspect rasters means that some of the original data is lost, so a re-created DEM can't be as accurate as the original. Have you looked to see if the original DEM is available online?

Comment: It is not online. In my case I am using proprietary data to create a map. The degradation of the DEM accuracy is not a concern.